# Status bar background color in iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ios14

Status bar background color in iOS14 not change.
Below extension works on iOS 13 or below.
Is something changed or deprecated?

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
    
          if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

              let tag = 3848245
              let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                  .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                  .compactMap({$0})
                  .first?.windows.first
    
              if let statusBar = keyWindow?.viewWithTag(tag) {
                  return statusBar
              } else {
                  let height = keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? .zero
                  let statusBarView = UIView(frame: height)
                  statusBarView.tag = tag
                  statusBarView.layer.zPosition = 999999
                  keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
                  return statusBarView
              }
          } else {
              if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
                  return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
              }
          }
          return nil
      }
}
```

Comment: Trying to give status bar a background color was always wrong.

Comment: Your code gets a reference to the status bar view just fine, I just tested it.  Where are you actually setting the background color?  That is most likely your problem.

Comment: in AppDelegate in DidFinishLaunch

Comment: UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .red

Comment: before iOS14 it worked right , after updating to iOS14 has problem

Comment: Try moving the code to set the color out of your `AppDelegate` and into your initial view controller.

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.